# merge two columns into one preserving the values of each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table that contains some data that I want to put in an array. The table layout can change from time to time and it is up to the user to decide what are the column header for each column (the column header becomes the key in the array. In the table there can be multiple columns with the same header but in that case the data are in one or the ohter column:

**all unique**

| Date | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | 100 |
| Second | row | -50 |

**duplicate header**

| Date | Description | Amount | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | 100 |  |
| Second | row |  | -50 |

Note that the order of the columns is defined by the user depending on the source of the table (a csv he uploaded to my application). The code I have so far works well with unique header and is able to spot the index of the duplicates.
For the duplicate situation the issue is that on row First it will return `Amount:''` because it will overwrite the former with the latter. On row Second it will return `Amount: '-50'` as expected. I need help to improve my code to have row First returning `Amount: '100'` in the duplicate situation.

My code:

```
$('.importer').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //quante colonne sono rimaste
        var cols= $(".tbi").find("tr:first th").length-1;
        //mappatura di ogni colonna
        var intestColonne = [];
        $('.tbi').find('tr:first th > select').each(function(){
            intestColonne.push($(this).val());
        });
        
        const importi=intestColonne.map((x, i) => x === 'importo' ? i : null).filter(x => x != null);
        //il pezzo commentato fa la stessa cosa della riga sopra
        /*intestColonne.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
        if (curr === 'importo') acc.push(i);
            console.log(acc);
            return acc;
        }, []);*/
        //leggo ogni colonna
        var movimenti=[];
        $('.tbi > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) { 
            var movimento = [];
            $(this).find('td').each(function(index,td){
                if(index<cols){
                    movimento[intestColonne[index]] = $(this).text();
//here I have to add something to manage the duplicate indexes that are stored in the importi const                             
                }else{
                    movimento['causale']= $(this).children('select').val();
                    movimento['segno']= $(this).children('select').find(':selected').data('segno');
                }
            });
            movimenti.push(movimento);
        });
        console.log(movimenti);
    });
```

The result for Second row will be like this

```
Array []
​​    causale: "3"
​​    data_cont: "19/01/2021"
​​    data_val: "19/01/2021"
​​    descr: "PRELIEVO BANCOMAT"
​​    importo: "-50"
​​    length: 0
​​    segno: "-"
```

while actually for row First it will be like

```
0: Array []
​​    causale: "3"
​​    data_cont: "19/01/2021"
​​    data_val: "19/01/2021"
​​    descr: "PRELIEVO BANCOMAT"
​​    importo: ""
​​    length: 0
​​    segno: "-"
```

while I'd like to have importo:"100" there

```js
$('.importer').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //quante colonne sono rimaste
        var cols= $(".tbi").find("tr:first th").length-1;
        //mappatura di ogni colonna
        var intestColonne = [];
        $('.tbi').find('tr:first th > select').each(function(){
            intestColonne.push($(this).val());
        });
        const importi=intestColonne.map((x, i) => x === 'importo' ? i : null).filter(x => x != null);
        
    //il pezzo commentato fa la stessa cosa della riga sopra
        /*intestColonne.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
        if (curr === 'importo') acc.push(i);
            console.log(acc);
            return acc;
        }, []);*/
        //leggo ogni colonna
        var movimenti=[];
        $('.tbi > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) { 
            var movimento = [];
            $(this).find('td').each(function(index,td){
                if(index<cols){
                    movimento[intestColonne[index]] = $(this).text();                               
                }else{
                    movimento['causale']= $(this).children('select').val();
                    movimento['segno']= $(this).children('select').find(':selected').data('segno');
                }
            });
            movimenti.push(movimento);
        });
        console.log(movimenti);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="importer">create array</button>
<table class="tbi">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><select name="tipo_mov0">
                    <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
                    <option value="data_val" selected>Data Valuta</option>
                    <option value="data_cont">Data Cont</option>
                    <option value="descr">Descrizione</option>
                    <option value="importo">Importo</option>
                </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
            <th><select name="tipo_mov1">
                    <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
                    <option value="data_val">Data Valuta</option>
                    <option value="data_cont" selected>Data Cont</option>
                    <option value="descr">Descrizione</option>
                    <option value="importo">Importo</option>
                </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
            <th><select name="tipo_mov2">
                    <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
                    <option value="data_val">Data Valuta</option>
                    <option value="data_cont">Data Cont</option>
                    <option value="descr" selected>Descrizione</option>
                    <option value="importo">Importo</option>
                </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
            <th><select name="tipo_mov4">
                    <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
                    <option value="data_val">Data Valuta</option>
                    <option value="data_cont">Data Cont</option>
                    <option value="descr">Descrizione</option>
                    <option value="importo" selected>Importo</option>
                </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
            <th><select name="tipo_mov5">
                    <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
                    <option value="data_val">Data Valuta</option>
                    <option value="data_cont">Data Cont</option>
                    <option value="descr">Descrizione</option>
                    <option value="importo" selected>Importo</option>
                </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
            <th>Causale</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>







        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>19/01/2021</td>
            <td>19/01/2021</td>
            <td>PRELIEVO BANCOMAT</td>
            <td>250.0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>19/01/2021</td>
            <td>16/01/2021</td>
            <td>PAGAMENTO POS </td>
            <td>60.0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>19/01/2021</td>
            <td>16/01/2021</td>
            <td>PAGAMENTO POS </td>
            <td>42.0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>15/01/2021</td>
            <td>15/01/2021</td>
            <td>ADDEBITO SDD</td>
            <td>1501.2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>15/01/2021</td>
            <td>13/01/2021</td>
            <td>PAGAMENTO POS </td>
            <td>167.31</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>11/01/2021</td>
            <td>06/01/2021</td>
            <td>PAGAMENTO UTENZE</td>
            <td>20.0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>08/01/2021</td>
            <td>05/01/2021</td>
            <td>PAGAMENTO POS </td>
            <td>7.88</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>07/01/2021</td>
            <td>06/01/2021</td>
            <td>PRELIEVO BANCOMAT</td>
            <td>250.0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <td>05/01/2021</td>
            <td>05/01/2021</td>
            <td>BONIFICO</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>900.0</td>
            <td class="text-danger"><select name="causali">
                    <option value="">Scegli</option>
                    <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
                    <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
                    <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
                    <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
                    <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
                    <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
                    <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you run the above snippet you will end up that only the last row will have a value for "Importo". All the other will have nothing. 250.0 in the first row will be overwritten by the second "Importo" column that is empty

Comment: _I need help to improve my code to have row First returning Amount: '100' in the duplicate situation_ as I said in the question

Comment: No, the array will handle unique keys (so "Amount" will be there just once) and I want to have it's value taken from the first or the second column based on where the value is

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, when you move to next cell, you want to grab the cell text value UNLESS it is empty and there is already a non empty grabbed value for this header.
So, the line

```
movimento[intestColonne[index]] = $(this).text();
```

should become

```
var oldText = movimento[intestColonne[index]];
var newText = $(this).text();
if (newText || !oldText) movimento[intestColonne[index]] = newText;
```

Comment: the sequence of the columns may vary and the two columns with the same header may not be one next to the other. Your code works if they are adiacent only

Comment: The code will work even if they are not adjacent. oldText is not the value of the previous index. It is the value of this header (importo for example), that we may -or may not- have found earlier. If an empty cell attempts to overwrite a previously acquired value, the code prohibits it

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this the wrong way, but I still have trouble with your explanations.
I nevertheless wrote this piece of code which I hope will help you (?)

```js
const
  TbHead = document.querySelector('table.tbi thead')
, TbBody = document.querySelector('table.tbi tbody')
  ;
btMergeCols.onclick =_=>
  {
  let cols = [...TbHead.querySelectorAll('th select[name^="tipo_mov"]' )]
    .map( selec => ({ lib:selec.value, col: selec.closest('th').cellIndex, smovN: selec.name }))
    .sort( (a,b)=> b.lib.localeCompare(a.lib) || b.col-a.col); // simplify test order.

  //console.log( JSON.stringify(cols,0,2)); 

  cols.forEach( (curElm,i,{[i+1]:nxtElm}) => 
    {
    if (!!nxtElm && curElm.lib===nxtElm.lib )
      {
      TbHead.rows[0].deleteCell(nxtElm.col);     console.log( `${curElm.smovN} (${curElm.lib}) is removed (duplicate)` );

      for (let r = 0; r < TbBody.rows.length; r++) 
        {
        let CurVal = TbBody.rows[ r ].cells[ curElm.col ].textContent.trim();

        if (CurVal !== '')
          TbBody.rows[ r ].cells[ nxtElm.col ].textContent = CurVal;

        TbBody.rows[r].deleteCell(curElm.col);
        }
      }
    })
 
  // create array part
  let movimenti = []
    , finalCols = [...TbHead.querySelectorAll('th select[name^="tipo_mov"]' )]
        .map( selec => ({ lib:selec.value, col: selec.closest('th').cellIndex }))
    ;
  [...TbBody.rows].forEach( row => 
    {
    let elm = {};
    movimenti.push(elm);
    finalCols.forEach( ({lib,col})=>
      {
      elm[lib] = row.cells[col].textContent.trim();
      });
    });

  console.log( JSON.stringify(movimenti,0,2 ));
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  margin      : 1rem;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : lightslategrey;
  }
tr { background-color: cadetblue;  }
td { background-color: whitesmoke; padding: .2em .5em; }
```

```html
<button id="btMergeCols"> merge duplicates columns / create array </button>
<br><br>

<table class="tbi">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <select name="tipo_mov0">
          <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
          <option value="data_val" selected>Data Valuta</option>
          <option value="data_cont">Data Cont</option>
          <option value="descr">Descrizione</option>
          <option value="importo">Importo</option>
        </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
      <th>
        <select name="tipo_mov1">
          <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
          <option value="data_val">Data Valuta</option>
          <option value="data_cont" selected>Data Cont</option>
          <option value="descr">Descrizione</option>
          <option value="importo">Importo</option>
        </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
      <th>
        <select name="tipo_mov2">
          <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
          <option value="data_val">Data Valuta</option>
          <option value="data_cont">Data Cont</option>
          <option value="descr" selected>Descrizione</option>
          <option value="importo">Importo</option>
        </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
      <th>
        <select name="tipo_mov4">
          <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
          <option value="data_val">Data Valuta</option>
          <option value="data_cont">Data Cont</option>
          <option value="descr">Descrizione</option>
          <option value="importo" selected>Importo</option>
        </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
      <th>
        <select name="tipo_mov5">
          <option value="">Tipo campo</option>
          <option value="data_val">Data Valuta</option>
          <option value="data_cont">Data Cont</option>
          <option value="descr">Descrizione</option>
          <option value="importo" selected>Importo</option>
        </select> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt bin"></i></th>
      <th>Causale</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>19/01/2021</td>
      <td>19/01/2021</td>
      <td>PRELIEVO BANCOMAT</td>
      <td>250.0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>19/01/2021</td>
      <td>16/01/2021</td>
      <td>PAGAMENTO POS </td>
      <td>60.0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>19/01/2021</td>
      <td>16/01/2021</td>
      <td>PAGAMENTO POS </td>
      <td>42.0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>15/01/2021</td>
      <td>15/01/2021</td>
      <td>ADDEBITO SDD</td>
      <td>1501.2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>15/01/2021</td>
      <td>13/01/2021</td>
      <td>PAGAMENTO POS </td>
      <td>167.31</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>11/01/2021</td>
      <td>06/01/2021</td>
      <td>PAGAMENTO UTENZE</td>
      <td>20.0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>08/01/2021</td>
      <td>05/01/2021</td>
      <td>PAGAMENTO POS </td>
      <td>7.88</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>07/01/2021</td>
      <td>06/01/2021</td>
      <td>PRELIEVO BANCOMAT</td>
      <td>250.0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-info">
      <td>05/01/2021</td>
      <td>05/01/2021</td>
      <td>BONIFICO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>900.0</td>
      <td class="text-danger">
        <select name="causali">
          <option value="">Scegli</option>
          <option value="1" data-segno="+">Stipendio</option>
          <option value="2" data-segno="-">Rata Mutuo</option>
          <option value="3" data-segno="-">Saldo carta di credito</option>
          <option value="4" data-segno="+">Interessi Attivi</option>
          <option value="5" data-segno="-">Interessi Passivi</option>
          <option value="9" data-segno="-">Spese banca</option>
          <option value="10" data-segno="-">giro a c/famiglia</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have updated my answer with your Table snippet

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have updated my answer again, adding 'create array'

Answer (score 0):

I spotted the solution by myself:

```
$(this).find('td').each(function(index,td){
                if(index<cols){
                    if(importi.includes(index)){
                        if($(this).text()!=''){
                            movimento[intestColonne[index]] = $(this).text();
                        }
                    }else{
                        movimento[intestColonne[index]] = $(this).text();
                    }
                }else{
                    movimento['causale']= $(this).children('select').val();
                    movimento['segno']= $(this).children('select').find(':selected').data('segno');
                }
            });
```

If I am on one of the columns marked as "Importo" `if(importi.includes(index)){` and the cell is not empty `if($(this).text()!=''){` then I push the value. Otherwise I will skip the cell. I had this in mind but was not able to write it on code before.